# Hide Email address in contact form without PHP

Tags: javascript, email, spam

I am using a hosting platform that does not use PHP, and changing is not an option. Is there any way I can hide an email address from my contact form when read in plain HTML?

The email address is held within an input tag, and I want it to be obscured when the plain HTML is read, but when the submit button is clicked the email address appears as normal/sends the email to the correct address.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cc_emails[]" value="email@domain.com" />
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

I am trying to do this to eliminate spam and bots being able to pick addresses up from plain HTML files.

Thanks!

Comment: keep this email address in Javascript variable and post form via Javascript.

Comment: Is this the email address to which the contact form sends the email to?

Comment: Yep thats correct, the form submits it's data to the email address in the input field

Comment: And the script on the server will send the date, do any email that is stored in `value="email@domain.com"`? If so then you have a much bigger problem, then a bot finding your email, namely that your server itself can be misused for spam. What is the reason that you store that email in the html document, and not in the php code?

Comment: @t.niese the hosting provider I'm using doesn't support PHP and changing is not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a js file and link it to the current HTML file.
Give id attribute to the input field, id="email"
And write the following in js file:

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "email@domain.com"
```

This will not show your email address in the HTML file. And will set the value too.

Comment: Ah very simple, Thank you very much!

Comment: For most bot it won't be a problem to find that email. @greystash